# How to search through all Paginated entry with AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I am using Jhipster. The Project has been generated with pagination. I need to search through all The IDs( entries), when I am searching anything, its only searching between the first 20  entries. how can I search through all entries ? is it possible to do with angularjs ? or it has to be done from server side ?

Given deafult **loadAll()** function:

```
$scope.loadAll = function() {
            DataEntry.query({page: $scope.page - 1, size: 20, sort: [$scope.predicate + ',' + ($scope.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc'), 'id']}, function(result, headers) {
                $scope.links = ParseLinks.parse(headers('link'));
                $scope.totalItems = headers('X-Total-Count');
                $scope.bundles = result;
            });
        };
```

I have tried so far

```
$scope.commonID = 1; //
$scope.newSetOfData = [];
$scope.searchNsort =function(){
        DataEntry.query(function(result){
                angular.forEach(result , function(dataResponse){
                    if(dataResponse.id == $scope.commomID){
                        $scope.newSetOfData.push(m);
                    }
                });
            });
            return $scope.newSetOfData;       
        };
```

Comment: Please see below link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738760/angularjs-search-on-the-entire-paginated-table

Comment: By default, only 20 entities are sent to the client (size: 20).  If you need to search all entities, you will need to set up an API on the server side, or use JHipster's elasticsearch option

Comment: Yes there was the problem. Fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On **ng-change** of search field I called this *filterData* function.**$scope.data** contain complete data.**$scope.searchValue** contain search value.I have set currentpage, numberperpage in $scope variable.This code is working for me.

```
 $scope.filterData = function(){

    if ($scope.data != undefined) {
        var filterData = $filter('filter')($scope.data,$scope.searchValue);
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
        end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
        $scope.data1 = filterData.slice(begin, end);
    }
  };
```